PDF file generated by Latex, how to extract (matlab/python) source code (verbatim/listings)
This is a bit bizarre. I have to review a bunch of PDF files, generated by Latex (but I don't have access to the source files) and that includes
matlab or python code, that was included with listings or verbatim.
How can I extract that code, without destroying its format?
Pdftotext, does not work well, copying with the mouse neither.
I gave mathpix a try, but it did not help either.
Does someone have an idea?
Thanks and regards
Uwe Brauer

the information is basically not there so you rely on whatever system you use to use heuristics to re-create the original white space. The description of "extracting without destroying the format" is misleading, the original format is not there.

thanks, that was precisely what I thought, but, for example there is mathpix, that uses some clever algorithm to convert, somehow, pdf (generated by LaTeX) back to latex, at least approximately. However it fails for source code (since it is interpreted as Latex). anyhow. Thanks

mathpix ignores the pdf internal structure it is doing ocr/ai on the screen image so a very fancy heuristic to infer structure from unstructured input

What should work, is marking several cod lines (pagewise), copy them and pasting into a plain-text editor, like notepad++. You may need columnwise delete to get rid of line numbers. // I never lookd up such pdf parts with an editor. Perhaps you can extract only those pages and let some script do the rest?

The problems are quoted text (strings) and similar things. These are usually not copied well
